# Angular JS Beginner Problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've recently been working on a simple APP with AngularJS. I've ran into some issues and I'm wondering if anybody could help?

Codebase:
https://github.com/WebDevLuke/AngularAddressBook

App:
http://lukeharrison.net/ng/

Anyhow, the first issue is that when I add a new contact, that contact doesn't appear on the page until I refresh, and then contacts are added and appear as you would expect them to be.

The second issue is that for some reason the $$hashKey on my NG-repeat isn't incrementing properly after the second contact addition and I eventually run into a "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed" error.

```
app.js:13639 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: contact in addressBook.contacts
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Not quite sure how I can be more specific then what has already been written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because there are duplicate items in your list, `addressBook.contacts`.

**Solution**

Just update your `ng-repeat` to

```
<div class="entry clearfix" ng-repeat="contact in addressBook.contacts track by $index | filter:{fullName:search}">
```

Comment: Hi, that seems to have sorted the issue somewhat. However everytime a new contact is added it's cloned across all the other contacts?

Comment: @Silveredge9, if it solves your issue, please do "Accept the answer" :)